# Can't open a USB port

Tags: drivers, usb

I have a single-board computer with a JTAG port serviced by FTDI hardware, but it's not connecting to the development system (Xilinx Vivado), and I'm trying to diagnose the problem.  The command
`sudo lsusb -v -D /dev/ttyUSB0`
reports `Cannot open /dev/ttyUSB0`, even though I've set permissions to 777 for the moment.  I ran `sudo usb-devices` with and without the cable connected to be sure I was looking at the right device and here's what I got (serial number obfuscated by me):

```
T:  Bus=01 Lev=03 Prnt=04 Port=01 Cnt=01 Dev#=  9 Spd=480 MxCh= 0
D:  Ver= 2.00 Cls=00(>ifc ) Sub=00 Prot=00 MxPS=64 #Cfgs=  1
P:  Vendor=0403 ProdID=6014 Rev=09.00
S:  Manufacturer=Digilent
S:  Product=Digilent USB Device
S:  SerialNumber=000000000000
C:  #Ifs= 1 Cfg#= 1 Atr=c0 MxPwr=0mA
I:  If#= 0 Alt= 0 #EPs= 2 Cls=ff(vend.) Sub=ff Prot=ff Driver=ftdi_sio
```

I'm running a fresh install of 18.04.2 just yesterday updated to 18.04.4; the reinstall was prompted by a desire to solve this problem, and I wanted to make sure stale software was not the cause.

I think the inability of Vivado to see the device may be related to the inability of a common system tool such as lsusb to open the device.  Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: The manpage for lsusb indicates that you are using -D incorrectly. It should look more like `sudo lsusb -v -D /dev/bus/usb/001/001`. Restore the permissions.

Comment: I got the same error, I think it's because `/dev/ttyUSB0` major number 188. Try to find this device in `/dev/bus/usb` and use with `lsusb -D`, on my machine for example it's `sudo lsusb -D /dev/bus/usb/003/119`. Notice that devices in /dev/bus/usb have major 189, defined as `#define USB_DEVICE_MAJOR  189` in Linux kernel.

Comment: Thanks!  That clears that problem.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, it has nothing to do with major numbers as I thought.  The `Cannot open /dev/ttyUSB0` message is printed in `dump_one_device()` if
pointer returned by `get_usb_device()` is NULL. This function in turn
calls `libusb_get_device_list()` that returns a list of USB devices
together with their bus and device numbers which are extracted using
`libusb_get_bus_number()` and `libusb_get_device_address()` and
concatenated with `"/dev/bus/usb"`.  You can check it with `gdb` (I've
used today's master commit c92f1962892d709cb9bad3aac2440932dd9684f6
from https://github.com/gregkh/usbutils):

```
$ gdb --args ./lsusb -vD /dev/ttyUSB0
Reading symbols from ./lsusb...done.
(gdb) break usbutils/usbmisc.c:134
Breakpoint 1 at 0x40b827: file usbmisc.c, line 134.
(gdb) run
Starting program: /media/data/usbutils/lsusb -vD /dev/ttyUSB0
[Thread debugging using libthread_db enabled]
Using host libthread_db library "/lib64/libthread_db.so.1".
[New Thread 0x7ffff6d44700 (LWP 4621)]

Thread 1 "lsusb" hit Breakpoint 1, get_usb_device (ctx=<optimized out>, path=path@entry=0x7fffffffddab "/dev/ttyUSB0") at usbmisc.c:134
134                     if (!strcmp(device_path, absolute_path)) {
(gdb) print device_path
$1 = "/dev/bus/usb/002/002", '\000' <repeats 4076 times>
(gdb) continue
Continuing.

Thread 1 "lsusb" hit Breakpoint 1, get_usb_device (ctx=<optimized out>, path=path@entry=0x7fffffffddab "/dev/ttyUSB0") at usbmisc.c:134
134                     if (!strcmp(device_path, absolute_path)) {
(gdb) print device_path
$2 = "/dev/bus/usb/002/001", '\000' <repeats 4076 times>
(gdb) continue
Continuing.

Thread 1 "lsusb" hit Breakpoint 1, get_usb_device (ctx=<optimized out>, path=path@entry=0x7fffffffddab "/dev/ttyUSB0") at usbmisc.c:134
134                     if (!strcmp(device_path, absolute_path)) {
(gdb) print device_path
$3 = "/dev/bus/usb/001/002", '\000' <repeats 4076 times>
(gdb) continue
Continuing.

Thread 1 "lsusb" hit Breakpoint 1, get_usb_device (ctx=<optimized out>, path=path@entry=0x7fffffffddab "/dev/ttyUSB0") at usbmisc.c:134
134                     if (!strcmp(device_path, absolute_path)) {
(gdb) print device_path
$4 = "/dev/bus/usb/001/001", '\000' <repeats 4076 times>
(...)
```

and so on until `device_path` is equal to the input argument.  Of
course `/dev/ttyUSB0` will never match.

It's nice that you can also change to /dev/bus/usb and pass a relative
device address:

```
$ cd /dev/bus/usb/
$ lsusb -D 001/001
Device: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
(...)
```